# Can I omit Reducer?

Tags: redux, react-redux, redux-saga

I'm using Redux and Redux Saga in a project. And I'm creating a notification system for the application. So, if any of the Sagas calls the success or failure actions, a success or failure notifications with will be shown.

I've put (called) the notification function in a Redux Saga.

```
SHOW_NOTIFICATION - action
showNotificationSaga = () => { notify({ message: 'Bla Bla' }) };
```

I don't see any reason to create a reducer here. I mean, I don't have any state to maintain for notifications. So, I'm thinking to not add any reducer for this.

Is this fine? Or an anti-pattern?

Thanks

Update:

Another approach could be to directly call `notify()` from the other sagas.

For example:

```
sagaForLogin(){
...catch(){
      notify({});
  }
}
```

Any recommendation?

Comment: If you don't need the state, then you don't need the reducer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If you don't need the state, then you don't need the reducer

I quote Ben because he's right.

The various sagas use actions to communicate between them and trigger themselves. So the actions haven't only the classic meaning of updating the state but they work also as communication/trigger events. Actions become so events in a pure event-driven development style (the one enforced by Resux-Saga).

Answer (score 0):

If the saga doesn't result in any state change, then maybe even the saga itself is not needed. If you have some indicators in store for success/failure actions, e.g. `isFetching` and `didInvalidate` as in [Redux website's example](https://redux.js.org/advanced/async-actions#designing-the-state-shape), you can create a props via `mapStateToProps` to let your component detect when and what to show notifications:

```
const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
    // passing indicators directly
    isFetching: state.myReducer.isFetching,
    didInvalidate: state.myReducer.isFetching
    // or compose into meaningful props
    somethingWrong: !state.myReducer.isFetching && state.myReducer.didInvalidate
})
```

Comment: I see two cases when an action doesn't result in a state change: 1 - the sagas are running an async flow that doesn't have a UI feedback (but the notification). 2 - avoid the components to care about the error notification showing (to avoid to decide which component should show up the notification). What do you think?

Comment: I mean: I don't see the need to make a component trigger the notification when a saga could do it byself (in case of a "long" async and saga-only flow)

Comment: Yes, I do agree with @NoriSte. I don't want my components to have any kind of logic or props to show notifications.

Comment: @NoriSte yes, I get your point. My assumption for the answer is that the async actions result in UI feedback, so using computed props with good implementation (e.g. memoized selector) will improve the performance instead of chain of sagas. If that's not the case then sagas should be used to avoid unnecessary renderings.